# Binding to attributes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a class

```
public class Car 
{
    [Description("name of the car")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Description("age of the car")]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any possibility to bind Description attribute to Label content. The solution what I'm looking for shouldn't require to instantiate Car object.

Comment: You shouldn't, that is an ugly way to populate your UI elements. What exactly are you trying to achieve - have a window autopopulated based on what it is bound to?

Comment: Yes, I want to get all labels in a Windows take their content from class properties attribute "Description". This attribute is used also for validation purposes.

Comment: You should bind your labels to text from a string resource file. Use DataTemplates if your bound item can change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It won't be a proper binding (which is not necessary for static data anyway) but you can easily create a [`MarkupExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.markupextension.aspx) to retrieve it, just pass the type and the property name and get it via reflection.

Outline would be something like:

```
public Type Type { get; set; }
public string PropertyName { get; set; }

ProvideValue: Type.GetProperty(PropertyName)
                  .GetCustomAttributes(true)
                  .OfType<DescriptionAttribute>()
                  .First()
                  .Description
```

```xml
<!-- Usage example -->
Text="{me:Description Type=local:Car, PropertyName=Name}"
```

Comment: I'm conflicted - you are showing him a way to do it, but you are also enabling him to create code that belongs in the depths of Mordor...

Comment: @slugster: I don't know, there are people using something like localized `DisplayName` attributes as well, could you explain why you have issues with that?

Comment: Localisation seems to be far from the OP's mind, and I suspect he is doing it this way because he is avoiding or doesn't know about data templates. In the absense of any explanation of the bigger picture I sense an impending train wreck.

Comment: @slugster: In a comment on the question "labels" were mentioned so if it is only used for that, not for the actual data, which should be bound to some control next to the label, it should be fine...

Answer (score 1):

You can't since it is an metadata of the property. You can workaround by creating a custom binding class.

Answer (score 1):

1 You create an `Converter`

```
public sealed class PropertyDescriptionConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return Binding.DoNothing;

            string propertyName = parameter as string;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
                return new ArgumentNullException("parameter").ToString();

            Type type = value.GetType();

            PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (property == null)
                return new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("parameter", parameter,
                    "Property \"" + propertyName + "\" not found in type \"" + type.Name + "\".").ToString();

            if (!property.IsDefined(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true))
                return new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("parameter", parameter,
                    "Property \"" + propertyName + "\" of type \"" + type.Name + "\"" +
                    " has no associated Description attribute.").ToString();

            return ((DescriptionAttribute)property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true)[0]).Description;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
```

2 You insert your ressource

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:PropertyDescriptionConverter x:Key="PropertyDescriptionConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
```

3 Add this binding

```
"{Binding ConverterParameter=Name, Converter={StaticResource PropertyDescriptionConverter}}"
```

Comment: The question explicitly notes that there is no instance.

Answer (score 1):

instead of string literal use string constant to set attribute parameter:

```
public class Car
{
    public const string CarNamePropertyDescription = "name of the car";
    
    [Description(CarNamePropertyDescription)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

constants can be accessed from xaml via `{x:Static}` extension (no need for Binding since attribute isn't going to change in runtime):

```
<Label Content="{x:Static namespace:Car.CarNamePropertyDescription}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well then create a reader class, which reads the attributes of the class and bind the attributes of the reader class. E.g.

```
public class Reader
{
   public Dictionary<string, string> Description {get; set;}
}
```